# Why is this JQuery not valid?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, html-helper, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I've been trying to figure out why this isn't valid (according to VS2008).

```
//Global variable
var sortFields;

$(document).ready(function() {
    sortFields = <%= CustomHtmlHelper.ToJson(ViewData["SortInfo"])%>;
    //Other Code here...
});
```

My HtmlHelper code

```
    public static string ToJson(object obj)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(obj);

        return json;
    }
```

The Helper is generating valid Json (confirmed it), but when I'm trying to add anything else to the function, VS2008 complains about all sort kinds of stuff, can't align the code correctly and so on when closing brackets, and as soon as I comment this out it works. However, the code works fine, even if VS2008 complains about it. 
Is this just VS2008 that is crap with JQuery or am I actually doing something wrong?

Comment: Is thin code in user control? Are you linking to jQuery in some other file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designer is *generally* going to get a bit upset when `<%=` is in script (and it sometimes gets snarly when it is in attribute values). If the output is correct, and you're happy with the way the html is constructed, then I wouldn't stress.

Ultimately, though; how does VS know that `ToJson` is going to return something sensible? It could return `"((((((("` which would **really** screw up the javascript. That is why it is unhappy.

Comment: Okay I see. I'm just a bit annoyed with it because I'm quite new to JQuery and I use the auto allignment to confirm that I've done valid code, and all of a sudden, it's not doing that anymore. So that's why. Thanks for quick reply!

Answer (score 2):

MrW,

you,ve got a missing bracket here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    sortFields = <%= CustomHtmlHelper.ToJson(ViewData["SortInfo"])%>;
    //Other Code here...
};
```

it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    sortFields = '<%= CustomHtmlHelper.ToJson(ViewData["SortInfo"])%>';
    //Other Code here...
**)};**
```

also, it may be better to return a jsonresult?? Also, add single quotes around the CustomHtmlHelper as shown above.

Comment: You're right about the **)};** but not the quotes. He wants an object literal here, not a string.

Comment: As Duncan sais, I want the object not a string. The last bracket was just typo now.